# How can I create an antlr tree of a given shape?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I've got an antlr grammar that has a rule like so:

```
rule:
ID (COMMA ID)*
;
```

where ID is a lexer rule for matching a typical variable name and comma is a lexer rule that matches a comma.  So the rule matches one or more comma separated variables

I'd like to create a tree that looks like so:

```
ITEM 
    ID
ITEM
    ID
....
```

where ITEM is an imaginary node that I insert in front of each ID that is found.

How would I do such a thing with the tree rewrite syntax?

Typically if I wanted to gather all the ids I'd just use

```
rule:
ID (COMMA ID)*  -> ^(ITEM ID+)
;
```

but this produces the tree:

```
ITEM
    ID 
    ID
    ....
```

I'm using C# if it matters as the implementation langauge and ANTLR 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to my senses quickly after asking the question.

To get the tree shape I'd like I need to use the rewrite syntax like so:

```
rule:
ID (COMMA ID)*  -> ^(ITEM ID)+
;
```